# How to efficiently insert a series of values into a std::deque?

Tags: c++, deque, c++03, capacity

I have some C++03 code to insert a series of values into a `std::deque`:

```
void example(std::deque<int> &_recentSent,
             const int beginOffset,
             const int lastOffset) {
  for (int offset = beginOffset; offset <= lastOffset; ++offset) {
    _recentSent.push_back(offset);
  }
}
```

If this were a `std::vector`, I would use `reserve()` to ensure the container was large enough for all the entries to be inserted before entering the loop:

```
std::vector<int> _recentSent;

_recentSent.reserve(_recentSent.size() + (lastOffset + 1 - beginOffset));
```

But since there is not one, what might I do to efficiently insert the series of items into the `std::deque` so that it is only resized once if necessary?

Comment: A deque isn't reallocated on expansion, so there's no benefit to reserving ahead of time.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, isn't a deque internally composed of "segments" of some given length, and when new memory is needed, a new segment is allocated?

Comment: Indeed.  But it's the key distinction is that storage isn't *reallocated*, therefore content never has to be moved (unlike in a vector).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ahh ok, yes, elements are not moved/copied around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike in a vector, the storage for a deque is never reallocated upon appending new elements.  That means that existing elements never have to be moved.  Thus there is no benefit to reserving ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `std::deque::reserve()`, what about preallocating all the storage by `_recentSent.resize (_recentSent.size () + lastOffset + 1 - beginOffset)` and then inserting using iterator `std::deque<int>::iterator it = _recentSent.end () - (lastOffset + 1 - beginOffset);`.